# Only the .lua extension type is showing.. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

for some reason after I installed Visual Studio Code the .lua extension shows even though the option in File Explorer is disabled.. I have googled for hours and even tried contacting Microsoft Support and even they couldn't help me. Any tech people out there are my last hope because I don't want to reinstall windows just to fix 1 little extension showing, sure it's annoying but I have 1TB+ of stuff that I don't want to reinstall..

Comment: iirc, the windows pref says "hide extensions for ***known*** file types". Is it a "known" file type? If you double click it, does it know what to open in?

Comment: You are an angel sent from god.. It doesn't say hide extensions for known file types (at least for me) but when I made it so it opens lua files with Visual Studio Code by default it instantly just poofed away.. I was just about to factory reset my computer right now too but you have saved me several hours of pain.. Thank you so, so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has a setting to "Hide extensions for ***known*** file types" *

[image]

So showing .lua would imply that it doesn't yet "know" what those files are or what they should open with.
As you said in comments, setting them to open with Visual Studio will then cause them to become "known" & the extension will then be hidden.

*It does in English - other languages may be different.